# "%1$s" is seen for message per conversation when pressing Restore default settings in Messaging Application

Tags: android

In Messaging Application, under Settings menu, if you select Restore default setting, the value's of Text message limit and Multimedia message limit changes to "%1$s". 
I tried setting android:defaultValue="200" in preferences.xml, but still, it's same behaviour.
Can anybody please let me know what changes i have to do for updating the value to default.
Thankyou

I understand, when exit the settings screen and come back to it, the default values (200 and 20) will be seen to have been restored correctly. but what i was looking for is, when selecting Restore default settings, how to updated the default value of Text message limit and Multimedia message limit
I wanted to know what changes are required to be done in java file, when selecting Restore default setting.
Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a programming error in generating the display. If you exit the settings screen and come back to it, the default values (200 and 20) will be seen to have been restored correctly.